# Rails Nested Forms - Dropdown menu on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form with nested fields, one of which is a drop-down menu:

```
<%= f.select :points, options_for_select([1, 0, -1]) %>
```

It works fine, but when I want to edit an item this field defaults to 1. How can I get the dropdown to select the saved value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) is the selected value so try setting that by:

```
<%= f.select :points, options_for_select([1, 0, -1], f.object.points) %>
```

or, you could pass the `selected` option as:

```
<%= f.select :points, options_for_select([1, 0, -1], selected: f.object.points) %>
```

Note that `f.object` has a reference to the current object for which this field is built so you can use it to get the appropriate attribute to default the selection to.